# The session returned by getSession is visible inside getServerSideProps but undefined inside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

When I console log `session` inside `Dashboard` it is returning `undefined` while console logging inside `getServerSideProps` is working and it is showing the details. Am I doing something wrong?

Goal: I am trying to get session information on `serverSideProps` (while making it a protected route to return the unauthenticated user back to the homepage), once I am done with getting session information I want to console log it (so I could continue my code and pass it down to component).

`dashboard.tsx`

```
import Details from '@/sections/Dashboard/Details';
import LatestCampaigns from '@/sections/Dashboard/LatestCampaigns';
import Footer from '@/sections/Footer';
import Navbar from '@/sections/Navbar'
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import { Session } from 'next-auth';
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import React from 'react';

export interface Props {
  session: Session | null
}

const Dashboard = ({ session }: Props) => {
  console.log(`Dashboard: ${session}`);
  console.info(session);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Details />
      <main>
        <LatestCampaigns />
        <Footer />
      </main>
    </>
  )
}

export default Dashboard;

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> = async (context) => {
  const _sess = await getSession(context);

  console.log('Checking..');
  console.info(_sess);

  if (!_sess) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false
      },
      props: {}
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      session: _sess
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried passing it down straight instead of using variable

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> = async (context) => {
  const session = await getSession(context);

  console.log('Checking..');
  console.info(session );

  if (!session ) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false
      },
      props: {}
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      session
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show an image of your file structure, especially where `Dashboard` is?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar, my guy you back again.. let me show you structure https://i.ibb.co/p20bBHF/structure.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`getServerSession`](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#getserversession)  since you are in `getServerSideProps`. `getSession()` is to be used only on the client, as they say on the [doc](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getsession):

> NextAuth.js provides a `getSession()` helper which should be called **client side only** to return the current active session.

Here is an example of how you would use `getServerSession`:

```
// [...nextauth].ts

import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // your configs
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

```
import { authOptions } from 'pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]'
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> = async (context) => {
  const session = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions);

  console.log(session);

  if (!session ) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false
      },
      props: {}
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      session
    }
  }
}
```